# Why does this Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite RewriteRule not work on 403s?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

In my `httpd.conf` I have:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And in my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I HTTP to `example.com/.ht` I expect to be redirected to `www.example.com/.ht`, but instead the RewriteRule never happens. The client is never redirected to www. The client is redirected properly in all other cases.

I don't have any ErrorDocument directives.

Just wondering why this happens and how to correct this behavior on 403's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to httpd.conf, there is no reason to use .htaccess.

What context is the FilesMatch in ? Is it inside a vhost ?

The following achieves the same result, but better:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/something
</VirtualHost>
```

There are no odd side-effects, either.

Comment: FilesMatch is in the global scope. I really prefer to use .htaccess if at all possible. If, however, you're telling me there's no way to achieve a redirect inside my .htaccess in the case of a 403, I may change my plans.

Comment: I'm not saying there is no way, but I will tell you that the order of request processing is different between htaccess and config.

Comment: Lesson learned: Scope is everything with Apache. This seems to be the best solution if you have access to your main httpd.conf file. Thanks.